# Uploading large images using jQuery and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, image-uploading, parse-error

I am using jQuery and PHP to upload images to the server and return a JSON of the cropped image.
My JavaScript code is:

```
$('document').ready(function () {

            $('#stat').hide();

            $('#file').on('change', function () {
                var fd = new FormData($('#target')[0]);
                $('#display > img').remove();
                $('#stat').show();

                $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo base_url('crop/upload') ?>',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: fd,
                    timeout: 1000 * 100,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                        $('#stat').hide();
                        $('div > img').remove();
                       console.log(data);
                        console.log(data[1].thumb);
                        $('#display > img').remove();
                        var img = $('<img>');
                        img.attr('src', data[1].thumb);
                        img.appendTo('#display')
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                       console.log(textStatus);
                    },
                    dataType: 'json'
                })

            })

        })
```

But whenever the image size is larger than **2 MB** the, I see  a parse error in the JS console. I tried to set a timeout, but it didn't work.

What is the problem? Does the browser sets a timeout?

How can I enable users to upload large images without  a **parse error** ?

Comment: You also have a timeout for PHP, to execute a script. Default is 30 seconds. Increase it in your `php.ini`

Comment: @Mysteryos i tried to set max_execution time for 5 min but it still returns parseerror after 1.2 min ?

Comment: There's also a limit on the size of the file that can be uploaded. Differs by host. **Apache:** `LimitRequestBody` shoud be zero. **Nginx: ** `client_max_body_size` should be `20M`. [Read this article to tweak your server limits](http://www.devside.net/wamp-server/apache-and-php-limits-and-timeouts)

Comment: @Mysteryos max_upload_filesize is set to 32M and i am try to run only 2MB jpeg file

Comment: @Mysteryos current i have set max_execution time to 3000s but it timeout after 40 seconds. Why so ?

Comment: Are you sure this is a server timeout? What is the http code for the response from the ajax call in your browser network console?

Comment: on successful response i should get something like this 
http://pastebin.com/qvYrJzz3

Comment: on error i get only 'parserror' in console, also there is not response from the server

Comment: @Mysteryos i checked the upload directory of the server. image is successfully uploading but it has problem in resizing it. here is the code. and i am using codeigniter. http://pastebin.com/UPM1psU4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69792/discussion-between-mysteryos-and-cody).

Answer (score 0):

increasing the memory allocated for PHP will solve the issue.

you can do it by:

1- Edit php.ini

`memory_limit = 128M`;
Or put code below to .htaccess

```
php_value memory_limit 128M
```

2-If you oftenly get this error and solution above isn’t work, contact your host. In most shared hosting, there is maximum memory_limit. You can’t set memory-limit to 64Mb if you get max 32Mb.